# Set Timezone to UTC-12

Tags: time-zones

How can I set the timezone to UTC-12?

I searched the regions and timezones supplied, but didn't find any TZ with UTC-12. Is there any possibility to set it by fiddling with configuration files?

Baker Island and Howard Island are in this TZ but they don't show up in the list.

Update:
Android Version 10
Build SHIFT6MQ.SOS.3.8.G.20220824

Comment: Fiddling with system files requires root access, e.g. [How to add timezone to world clock when you don't know the city?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/45502/44325), [How to update timezone data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/104962/44325)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am putting the solution here instead of the comments as previously done.

1. Go to Settings -> System -> Date & time.
2. Set `Automatic time zone` to off.
3. Press on `Select time zone`
4. Press the 3-dot,
5. Press `Select by UTC offset`. GMT-12:00 will be listed. Select it.